# Joining Pandas Dataframes w/ multiple joins

Tags: python, pandas, join

I am trying to join in the information from df_demog for each column in df.  The below example only brings it in for compar1, but ideally would like to join in the 4 pieces of information from df_demog for each of the 6 columns in df.

I could write 6 join clauses but would ideally like to learn how to make it more efficient (if possible) in one join.

thanks

---expected output--------
[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'compar1': [1],
        'compar2': [2],
     'compar3':[3],
     'compar4':[4],
     'compar5':[5],
     'compar6':[6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

```
df_demog = {'EID': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'gender': ['m','w','m','m','y','m'],
           'vm':['y','n','y','n','y','n'],
           'age':[22,33,54,53,22,12]}
df_demog = pd.DataFrame(df_demog)
```

```
df_out=df.join(df_demog, lsuffix="compar1", rsuffix="EID")
df_out
```

Comment: can you share the expected output (at least a half of it) ?

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest - thanks, added a picture of expected output... essentially keeping the data in 'wide' format where all the data comes in as columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df_demog` dataframe can be stacked to obtain full-range columns/values for further `join`:

```
st = df_demog.stack()
df_out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'{j}_{i}' for i in (st.index.levels[0] + 1)
                                       for j in st.index.levels[1]], data=[st.values]))
print(df_out)  # one row output
```

---

```
   compar1  compar2  compar3  compar4  compar5  compar6  EID_1 gender_1 vm_1  \
0        1        2        3        4        5        6      1        m    y   

   age_1  EID_2 gender_2 vm_2  age_2  EID_3 gender_3 vm_3  age_3  EID_4  \
0     22      2        w    n     33      3        m    y     54      4   

  gender_4 vm_4  age_4  EID_5 gender_5 vm_5  age_5  EID_6 gender_6 vm_6  age_6  
0        m    n     53      5        y    y     22      6        m    n     12
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thnx so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
df_col_merged = pd.concat([df, df_demog], axis=1)
df_col_merged.loc[1:5] = df_col_merged.loc[1:5].fillna(df_col_merged.loc[0])
df_col_merged
```

Try this

Comment: Is this efficient or you need it more efficient? Because I imagine that a for loop may work.

Comment: Hi Mateo - thanks very much.  Is there a way to keep the format all in a single row with the columns appended to the right (output picture above, if it is possible)